# What are the methods to increase capacity for local in usr in linux?

Tags: lvm, disk, volume

I have a linux production virtual machine and I need to increase space in `/usr/local` folder. I have already attached a partitioned and formatted disk with capacity of 300 GB as follows.

```
[root@CentOS6-4SVR ~]# df -hT
Filesystem           Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                     ext4   433G  373G   39G  91% /
tmpfs                tmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1           ext4   477M   46M  406M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                     ext4    41G   10G   29G  26% /home

[root@CentOS6-4SVR ~]# lsblk              
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdb                        202:16   0  400G  0 disk 
└─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0)   253:0    0  440G  0 lvm  /
xvda                        202:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─xvda1                     202:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─xvda2                     202:2    0 99.5G  0 part 
  ├─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  440G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VolGroup-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0 41.7G  0 lvm  /home
xvdc                        202:32   0  300G  0 disk 

[root@CentOS6-4SVR ~]# vgdisplay          
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               499.50 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              127873
  Alloc PE / Size       125314 / 489.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       2559 / 10.00 GiB
  VG UUID               jH8M8M-P8ey-apiK-888r-OhDj-ERSf-bn13N9
```

Please mention available methods to do that ?

***Edit 01***

I tried to extend as follow, but I got following errors. Please advice.

```
[root@csc-akaza-test-01 ~]# pvcreate /dev/xvdc
  Couldn't find device with uuid gBPzEJ-Ir84-Q8pw-IJ8J-Bh10-ISIy-1snfWG.
  Couldn't find device with uuid d4eTfV-HR7R-TLeH-tYgy-e2JC-B6sl-d5ysHa.
  Physical volume "/dev/xvdc" successfully created

[root@csc-akaza-test-01 ~]# vgextend VolGroup /dev/xvdc
  Couldn't find device with uuid gBPzEJ-Ir84-Q8pw-IJ8J-Bh10-ISIy-1snfWG.
  Couldn't find device with uuid d4eTfV-HR7R-TLeH-tYgy-e2JC-B6sl-d5ysHa.
  Volume group "VolGroup" successfully extended

[root@csc-akaza-test-01 ~]# lvresize -r -l 100%FREE VolGroup/lv_root
  Couldn't find device with uuid gBPzEJ-Ir84-Q8pw-IJ8J-Bh10-ISIy-1snfWG.
  Couldn't find device with uuid d4eTfV-HR7R-TLeH-tYgy-e2JC-B6sl-d5ysHa.
  Cannot change VG VolGroup while PVs are missing.
  Consider vgreduce --removemissing.
  Cannot process volume group VolGroup
```

Comment: 1. Add a new virtual disk and mount it at /usr/local or 2. add a new virtual disk and add it to the volume group VolGroup, then increase the size of VolGroup-lv_root. It is interesting that your 300GB disk has over 383GB disk space used already.

Comment: The messages in your Edit 01 indicate that two PVs have been removed from the system without reducing them out of the VG. **Your system might have difficulties rebooting unless you fix this.** Please run `vgdisplay -v`, find the `--- Physical volumes ---` heading and look for the UUIDs listed in the error messages. If those PVs are listed as empty (= their Total PE is equal to Free PE), then you can safely use the suggested `vgreduce --removemissing` command to delete the missing PVs from the LVM configuration. Otherwise, `pvdisplay --maps` is needed for further analysis.

Comment: `vgreduce --removemissing` not working how can I resolve that using this command please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using LVM already and don't have a filesystem mounted at `/usr/local`, you can simply add the new disk (partition actually) to the volume group and then increase the size of the root logical volume and filesystem:

```
pvcreate /dev/xvdc1
vgextend VolGroup /dev/xvdc1
lvresize -r -l 100%FREE VolGroup/lv_root
```

### WARNING

You're dealing with a production system. Ensure you understand the commands shown above *BEFORE* you use them. In following my advice you take full responsibility for whatever may happen.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions and advises and I got this `[root@csc-akaza-test-01 ~]# pvcreate /dev/xvdc1   Couldn't find device with uuid gBPzEJ-Ir84-Q8pw-IJ8J-Bh10-ISIy-1snfWG.
  Couldn't find device with uuid d4eTfV-HR7R-TLeH-tYgy-e2JC-B6sl-d5ysHa.
  Physical volume "/dev/xvdc" successfully created`  @Emmanuel Rosa